# C++ out-of-namespace definition

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-lookup

On [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) site there is the following paragraph:

> Out-of-namespace definitions and redeclarations are only allowed after the point of declaration, only at namespace scope, and only in namespaces that enclose the original namespace (including the global namespace) [**and they must use qualified-id syntax (since C++14)**]

I used [] to delimit the section that the `(since C++14)` construct refers to.

My question is how were out-of-namespace definitions made before C++14, if they did not have to use `qualified-id syntax`?

I looked at a C++11 standard draft and I found the following:

> Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that namespace by **explicit qualification (3.4.3.2)**
>   of the name being defined, provided that the entity being defined was already declared in the namespace
>   and the definition appears after the point of declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s
>   namespace. [...]

Is there a difference between `qualified-id syntax` and `explicit qualification`?

Thank you.

Comment: Cppreference is just showing a (probably incorrect) summary of [CWG 1838](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1838)

Comment: Looks like [Core Defect 1021](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1021) might be relevant. (which relates to 1838 as mentioned by cpplearner^)

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. So they explicitly say that one must `use qualified-id syntax` so that one is not allowed to make such a definition using a combination of `using` + `unqualified name definition`. Also, the resolution for defect 1838 also solves defect 1021.

Comment: `namespace mine { void f(); } void mine::f() { /* whatever */ }`.